# Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lista

Possuo o seguinte método abaixo com o propósito de retornar notificações que devem ser exibidas para determinado cliente e notificações que devem ser exibidas para todos os clientes.

```
public List<TNotification> GetNotifications(TClient client)
{
    var notificacoesClient = Session.CreateCriteria<TNotification>()
        .CreateAlias("TClientNotifications", "clientNotifications", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
        .SetFetchMode("clientNotifications.Client", FetchMode.Eager)
        .CreateAlias("clientNotifications.Client", "client", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("client.Id", client.Id))
        .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"))
        .List<TNotification>()
        .ToList();

    var notificacoesAll = Session.CreateCriteria<TNotification>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsToAll", true))
        .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"))
        .List<TNotification>()
        .ToList();

    return notificacoesAll.Union(notificacoesClient);
}
```

Porém na instrução `return notificacoesAll.Union(notificacoesClient);` está retornando a seguinte mensagem:

> Cannot implicity convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Como poderia resolver esta questão?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este erro acontece porque `notificacoesAll.Union(notificacoesClient)` retorna um `IEnumerable<TNotification>`, mas a assinatura do seu método espera `List<TNotification>`.

Logo, você tem duas alternativas:

- Alterar a assinatura do seu método para retornar `IEnumerable<TNotification>`
- Transformar o resultado da sua união em uma lista:

  ```
  return notificacoesAll.Union(notificacoesClient).ToList();
  ```

Mais um detalhe: creio que não seja necessário chamar `ToList`nas queries do seu exemplo, pois `List` já retorna  uma lista (é redundante).

Answer (score 2):

Tire o `.ToList()` das lista e deixe apenas no retorno

Algo assim:

```cs
public List<TNotification> GetNotifications(TClient client)
{
    var notificacoesClient = Session.CreateCriteria<TNotification>()
        .CreateAlias("TClientNotifications", "clientNotifications", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
        .SetFetchMode("clientNotifications.Client", FetchMode.Eager)
        .CreateAlias("clientNotifications.Client", "client", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("client.Id", client.Id))
        .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"))
        .List<TNotification>();

    var notificacoesAll = Session.CreateCriteria<TNotification>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsToAll", true))
        .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"))
        .List<TNotification>();

    return notificacoesAll.Union(notificacoesClient).ToList();
}
```

Comment: siga essas regras para [criação ou edição de perguntas e respostas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) +1 pela resposta.